# How to save big XML file in java class as String?

Tags: java, xml

I want to save big XML as a string in my java class. So that I will convert that string to document and I will manipulate.

the problem here is there are hundreds of tags. for each tag in a different line need to be prefixed and suffixed with double-quotes.

there will be special characters in XML like closing tag.

Comment: Do not understand. Please edit the question and show examples

Comment: Don't do that. Store it as a resource and load it using e.g. `getClass().getResourceAsInputStream(...)` .

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.  Have you considered putting the XML into a file in the file system or a resource on the classpath ... and then reading it into memory as a stream?

Comment: Currently, there's no way to get around the need to escape all those characters. There's a proposal to improve that in the future, but it won't be available at least until JDK 13. https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/12/jdk-12-new-features